# How-to: Remove text from Word document footer using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, interop, ms-word, com-interop, footer

I'm trying to remove a footer from a Word document using C# 4.  The footer looks like this:

> Page 1 April 18, 2012

Actually, this the text for the footer when displayed in Word VBA:

> Page 1 ( April 18, 2012

There's actually a bullet character between "Page 1" and "April".  In the end the footer should look like this:

> April 18, 2012

Anyway, in Word VBA, I'm able to do it using this code:

```
Dim rngFtr As Range
Set rngFtr = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
rngFtr.Collapse wdCollapseStart
rngFtr.MoveStart wdParagraph, 1
rngFtr.MoveEnd wdWord, 4
rngFtr.Delete
```

I tried the same thing in C# but it removes the footer entirely.  Here's my code in C# 4:
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document doc = ap.Documents.Open(docFile.FullName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
doc.Activate();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range ftrRng =
    doc.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
ftrRng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
ftrRng.MoveStart(WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1);
ftrRng.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdWord, 4);
ftrRng.Delete();

ap.Documents.Close(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: false, RouteDocument: false);

((_Application) ap).Quit(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: false, RouteDocument: false);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ap);
```

I even tried other ways to get rid of "Page 1" & the bullet, such as:

```
var replaceText = string.Empty;
object mis = System.Type.Missing;
var targetFooterText =
    doc.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Text.ToString().Substring(1, 10);
doc.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Find.Execute(
    targetFooterText,
    ref mis, ref mis, ref mis, ref mis, ref mis, ref mis, ref mis, ref mis,
    replaceText,
    ref mis, ref mis, ref mis, ref mis, ref mis);
```

This doesn't do anything.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you in advance.

I'm not sure if this is important, but the bullet is a Unicode-2022.

Here's a screen cap of the document footer.  I just need to remove the text "Page 1" & bullet and replace it with the date.  The rest should remain as is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and playing around with Word VBA, I was able to find an alternate solution.  Here's my final code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Document doc = ap.Documents.Open(docFile.FullName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
doc.Activate();

// These 3 lines did the trick.
doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekPrimaryFooter;
doc.Application.Selection.MoveRight(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
doc.Application.Selection.Delete(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 9);

ap.Documents.Close(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: false, RouteDocument: false);

((_Application) ap).Quit(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: false, RouteDocument: false);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the example below, it does the following:

- Extract all the text from the footer range
- Remove the "Page" string from the text
- Set the footer range text to the previous value minus the "Page"

  ```
      using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

      Word.Document document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;

      Word.Range footerRange =
          document.Sections[1].Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;

      string rangeText = footerRange.Text;

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rangeText) && rangeText.Contains("Page"))
      {
          //Now set the footer Range Text to the new value minus the "Page"
          //Note: Edit as required because the page number may not always be one character
          string newValue = rangeText.Remove(rangeText.IndexOf("Page"), 6);
          footerRange.Text = newValue;
      }
  ```

Comment: It didn't work.  I should add that on the right of the footer I have a logo.  I only want to replace the text but keep all formats & logos/images where it is.  Can that be done?

Comment: Could you post a picture of your footer so I can attempt to replace the required text while still preserving the logo etc where it should be